# AWS Custom Event Patterns for AWS Event Bridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am new to EventBridge and needs to create a *custom event patterns* that would invoke the specific target (Lambda) once *after 60 minutes* on the rule being created. Given that I am using a custom application, I am unable to use the ScheduleExpression.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify, what's wrong with `ScheduleExpression`?

Comment: @Marcin, for EventBidge's custom Event Bus, ScheduleExpression is not allowed. Expressions must be done in Event Patterns.